# Ruby on Rails: Using a private repo (Yarn package) and deploying with Chef Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, chef-infra, yarnpkg

My rails app is deployed via Chef, and I'm having trouble cloning a private repo of a Yarn package into my project upon deployment. Linking to the private repo works just fine locally. The repo is hosted at my company's internal GitHub URL (github.mycompany.com). The app also uses a private repo for a gem, and that retrieval works just fine. The issue comes about when Chef tries to run `rails:assets:precompile` on the production server:

```
       Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_execute[rake assets:precompile]'
       ================================================================================

       Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
       ------------------------------------
       Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
       ---- Begin output of ["/opt/ruby_build/builds/system/bin/ruby", "/opt/ruby_build/builds/system/bin/bundle", "exec", "/opt/ruby_build/builds/system/bin/ruby", "/var/www/app_name/releases/latest/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/rake", "assets:precompile"] ----
       STDOUT: yarn install v1.21.1
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
       STDERR: error Command failed.
       Exit code: 128
       Command: git
       Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads git@<repo_location>.git
       Directory: /var/www/app_name/releases/latest
       Output:
       Load key "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied

       Permission denied (publickey).

       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

       Please make sure you have the correct access rights
       and the repository exists.
```

This is my first time using Yarn. I have read some issues on the Yarn repo about cloning private repos, but I think this situation is a bit different. This setup also works fine for all our other Rails apps that don't use any private yarn repos.

1) Why would the permission be denied to my SSH key? It's created from a deploy_key in a data bag, and like I said before works just fine for installing a private gem repo (we have a Chef GitHub user, which is added as a collaborator on both the gem and yarn repos).

2) Is there a way to completely package this repo inside my project, precompile assets locally, then force our production server to serve the precompiled assets from the /public folder? This doesn't feel right to me but it might be an acceptable workaround for now.

Comment: Did you add key the key stored in `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa` to github? Could the issue be that thats not really your deploy key at all?

Comment: It looks like the id_rsa key doesn't exist on the chef server, but there are several deploy keys that are generated that work fine in other cases. How can I tell yarn to use those keys instead? I've seen some things online about using an SSH wrapper for this but not sure how to proceed.